# How to print out dict into CLI app and have clean code

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, command-line-interface

I have a class that has set dict (constant), looks like this:

```
EDIT_OPTION_CHOICES = {
        'A': 'Add cards',
        'D': 'Delete cards',
        'O': 'Reorder cards',
        'C': 'Change card content',
        'R': 'Rename stack',
        'Q': 'Quit'
        }
```

It serves for printing out options for users. Each letter is basically a key press. Right now I'm using this piece of code:

```
    keys = [key for key, val in self.EDIT_OPTION_CHOICES.items()]
    vals = [val for key, val in self.EDIT_OPTION_CHOICES.items()]

    print "Select: (%s) %s (%s) %s (%s) %s (%s) %s (%s) %s (%s) %s" % (
            keys[0], vals[0], keys[3], vals[3], keys[1], vals[1], keys[4], vals[4], 
            keys[2], vals[2], keys[5], vals[5])
```

I have another function that evaluates user's input and I'd like to avoid this:

```
    if subprompt == self.EDIT_OPTION_CHOICES.items()[0]:
```

Because it's kinda hard to read from code which option I'm actually evaluating. (I mean I could do `if subprompt in keys` by using the same `keys` list from previous function.

I don't know it just seems awful lot of code for such a small task. Is there a better way?

Also that printout doesn't have exactly the order I'd like to use (hence the shuffled indexes) because I use dictionary. I guess I could go with `EDIT_OPTION_CHOICES.items()` and order it somehow but I'm not sure if it makes things easier.

Comment: You start with `EDIT_OPTION_CHOICES` but then make your keys and values from `EDIT_STACK_CHOICES`. It's kind of distracting.

Comment: sorry, paste error. fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, definitely. You can use list comprehensions. Here's a one liner that does it:

```
" ".join("(%s) %s" % i for i in EDIT_OPTION_CHOICES.items())
```

What this does, is it joins by spaces, a string formatted in the desired way for each of the items.

About the sorting, just use sort <strike>with a key</strike> using python's default sort with tuples, giving us:

```
" ".join("(%s) %s" % i for i in sorted(EDIT_OPTION_CHOICES.items())
```

This sorts by the letter.

I'm not sure what you mean about the subprompt thing.

Comment: Since python already sorts in index order, the `key` parameter is redundant isn't it?

Comment: @user3267581 good point, forgot about python's awesome sorting.